# Upload Image PHP rename file

Tags: php, image-processing

I am very much a beginner when it comes to PHP, however, I seemed to have my image uploader working the way I want to with the following code (sourced online). The only issue is I need to rename the files when the user uploads them to something unique like the user/date. I cannot seem to get it working when I alter this code.

I have spent some time searching here and the internet in general but I have struggled to find something that fits.

Please could someone offer me a fix or direct me in the right direction.

Thank You Stack Overflow,

```html
class Uploader {
 
 private $files = array();
 private $extensions = array();
 private $errors = array();
 
 private $store_directory = "./attachment";
 private $resize_image_library_instance = null;
 
 public function __construct($files) {
  if (is_array($files) === false) {
   $files[] = $files;
  }

  $this->files = $files;
 }
 
 public function set_upload_to($store_directory) {
  $this->store_directory = $store_directory;
 }
 
 public function set_valid_extensions($extensions, $case_sensitive = false) {
  $this->extensions = $extensions;
  $this->case_sensitive = $case_sensitive;
 }
 
 public function set_resize_image_library($resize_image_library_instance) {
  $this->resize_image_library_instance = $resize_image_library_instance;
 }
 
 public function is_valid_extension() {
  $total = count($this->files);
  for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
   if (empty($this->files['name'][$i]) === false) {
    $file_extension = $this->get_extension($this->files['name'][$i]);
   
    if (in_array($file_extension, $this->extensions) === false) {
     $this->errors['type'] = "extension";
     $this->errors['file_name'] = $this->files['name'][$i];
     $this->errors['file_extension'] = $file_extension;
     return false;
    }
   }
  }
  return true;
 }
 
 public function run() {
  $total = count($this->files);
  for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
   if (empty($this->files['name'][$i]) === false) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($this->files['tmp_name'][$i], $this->store_directory.'/'.$this->files['name'][$i]) == false) {
     $this->errors['type'] = "run";
     $this->errors['file_name'] = $this->files['name'][$i];
    }
   }
  }
  
  return empty($this->errors);
 }
 
 public function resize($scale_size = 200) {
  $total = count($this->files);
  for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
   $image = realpath($this->store_directory.'/'.$this->files['name'][$i]);
   
   if (file_exists($image) === true && is_file($image) === true) {
    $this->resize_image_library_instance->init($image);
    $this->resize_image_library_instance->scale($scale_size);
    if ($this->resize_image_library_instance->save($image) === false) {
     $this->errors['type'] = "resize";
     $this->errors['file_name'] = $image;
    }
   }
  }
  
  return empty($this->errors);
 }
 
 public function get_errors() {
  return $this->errors;
 }
 
 //
 private function get_extension($filename) {
  $info = pathinfo($filename);
  return $info['extension'];
 }
 
 private function get_filename($file) {
  $info = pathinfo($file);
  return $info['filename'];
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate an unique name for the uploaded file and save it to server you can use the time(), mt_rand() and then the uploaded file's name together. Like this..

```
public static function generateUniqueFileName($fileName)
{
    return time() . mt_rand(100, 100000) . $fileName;
}
```

And if you want to pre-pend the username as well then you can pass it to the method and concat it in the beginning.